# Jekyll data manual output order

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How can I output items from a data file in a specific order?

---

Let's say that my data file looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Tim"
}, {
    "name": "Paul"
}, {
    "name": "Brian"
}, {
    "name": "James"
}, {
    "name": "Mark"
}]
```

Without really putting enough tought into it, I wrote the following:

```
{% for item in site.data.example %}

  {% if
    item.name == "Mark" or
    item.name == "Brian" or
    item.name == "James"
  %}
  <div>
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

...which will obviously output:

```
<div>Brian</div>
<div>James</div>
<div>Mark</div>
```

...when I wanted the order to be:

```
<div>Mark</div>
<div>Brian</div>
<div>James</div>
```

I couldn't come up with a way to force a specific order, other than changing the order in the data file, but that is not a viable option for me.

Comment: P.S. I don't have have much experience working with data files in general.

Comment: Is that a json data file?

Comment: @marcanuy, yes it is.

Comment: So it can't be modified?

Comment: @marcanuy, yea, definitely not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index with the desired order, it could be in another data file or directly as a Liquid array.

Then for each item in the index, traverse the data file processing chosing the one that matchs it:

```
{% assign listorder = "Mark,Brian,James" |split: ","%}
{% for order in listorder %}
{% for data in site.data.mydata %}
{% if data['name']==order%}
{{data['name']}},
{% endif %}
{% endfor%}

{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
 Mark, Brian, James,
```

## To have the order in a data file

Create `_data/order.yml`:

```
- Mark
- Brian
- James
```

Then in the code use: `{% for order in site.data.order %}`

Comment: Thanks. Of you don't mind me asking... Is there a way to make this into a custom function (or something), so that I could use it in multiple spots in different pages. Like:`getInfo( "Mark, Brian, James" )` and `getInfo( "Brian, Paul, Tim")`. I'm not insisting on using this exact format, just need to look into a way to repeat this code in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Best option would be to create multiple data files with the order, I've updated the question with it.

Comment: Sadly, that isn't an option, since we are talking about a 50MB json file, which can't be edited manually and each batch of data I pick out of it needs to be in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Check jekyll **includes**, that would do what you are looking for.

Comment: At first I was like "Are you super sure...", but yea. That works. Didn't know include could take parameters. **Thanks!**